# Linear Layout in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

     int N = 10; 
     TextView[] myTextViews = new TextView[N]; 
    LinearLayout myLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.test);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
         TextView rowTextView = new TextView(this);
        rowTextView.setText(message);

        myLinearLayout.addView(rowTextView);
        myTextViews[i] = rowTextView; }
```

What is the error in the above code? 
"Unfortunately the app has stopped" error is shown.

Comment: Can you show more of the error? Maybe copy-paste the whole trace?

Comment: could be anything, and could be unrelated to your code here. post your stacktrace

Answer (score 3):

You aren't calling `setContentView()` anywhere. Try using:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.id.<yourlayout>);
    //Your code
```

You can't reference Views in your layout unless it's been inflated. Calling `findViewById()` looks for the View in the current layout. As you do not have a layout set, you'll get a null value for `myLinearLayout`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're displaying 10 simple text items, one on top of the other, you may want to think about a ListView instead.  The Eclipse plugin will generate you a sample app with a ListView filled from a static array right out of the box.  Just select `New > Other... > Android > Android Application Project > [name app] > [create icon (optional)] > MasterDetailFlow`